# Disabling the Dialog pop-up for Calendar views

Tags: modal-dialog, sharepoint-calendar

It seems from my trivial Google searches, that some users find, for certain list types - an inconsistent experience related to modal dialogs.

In my scenario, we have a plain old SharePoint Foundation server, and on our particular sub site's Calendar, we have gone into 'List Settings' > 'Advanced Settings' and have turned off the 'Launch forms in a dialog' setting.

It seems to have no effect except for certain views of the calendar (we have a plain list view of the calendar -not by week/month/day or anything.. just a straight list rendering- where it does seem to work)

I'm wondering what's up with this?

*EDIT*

For the meantime, I'm can use jQuery to deactivate the dialog functionality. But, it gets ignored if users click the left-hand calendar widget to jump to various dates (the ajax refresh kills off the DOM that was affected by my jQuery)

```
jQuery('div#WebPartWPQ1 a').removeAttr('onclick');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dialogs` setting only affects List Views rendered via [XsltListViewWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.listviewwebpart.aspx).

Specific List Views like  Calendar (your case), Gantt or Chart Views are rendered via [**ListViewWebPart**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.listviewwebpart.aspx).
The point is that Dialogs setting **does not take into account** when a List View is rendered via [**ListViewWebPart**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.listviewwebpart.aspx). And the message on the List settings page:

> Dialogs that may not be available on all forms

concerns exactly this situation.

### How to open calendar forms as a full pages

The idea is to specify explicitly `NavigateForFormsPages` parameter for `ContextInfo` structure (for more details please follow this post [Understanding the List Dialogs setting in SharePoint 2010](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/08/18/understanding-the-list-dialogs-setting-in-sharepoint-2010/) )

Steps:

1. Add [CEWP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.contenteditorwebpart.aspx) into Calendar View page (`Calendar.aspx`)
2. Place the following JavaScript code into [CEWP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.contenteditorwebpart.aspx)

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">

   var ContextInfo = (function() {
       var ContextInfo_Orig = ContextInfo;

       return function() {
               ContextInfo_Orig();
               this.NavigateForFormsPages = true; // Set navigate to the full page for list forms links
       }

   })();
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can add the following link to your left navigation as "New Calender Event" and include the below link

```
sitename/Lists/Calenderlistname/NewForm.aspx?RootFolder=Lists%2FCalenderListName&ContentTypeId=0x010200482D7C3F07C0694984DEC8DD23D8A2D7002E021C99EA80B4438C58E54ABECCC335
```